# Lab4 - trying to understand what I'm supposed to do

Tags: python

This is what I have to do; "Assume that you have the coordinates (x,y) of four points p1, p2, p3, and p4. Write a function name
check_is_square() that asks the user for the coordinates of those four points (total of eight integer inputs) and prints the message Yes – it is a Square if those four points can form a square on the coordinate plane and the message No – it is not a square otherwise. Call check_is_square()from the main() function."

This is the code I have currently;

```
import math
def check_square(x1,x2,y1,y2):
 if (math.sqrt((x1 - x2)**2+(y1-y2)**2) % 2 == 0): 
  print("Yes - it is a square")
 else:
  print("No - it is not a square")
def main():
 x1 = int(input("Enter coordinate 1: "))
 x2 = int(input("Enter coordinate 2: "))
 y1 = int(input("Enter coordinate 3: "))
 y2 = int(input("Enter coordinate 4: "))
 check_square(x1,x2,y1,y2)
main()
```

Comment: You are asked for four points each of which consists of an x value and a y value, so your input stage cannot be correct as it collects only two points.

Comment: The question also seems a bit fuzzy around `check_square`. Checking the magnitude of opposing (or all) sides (which it seems like your doing) doesn't guarantee that your 4 points form a square (i.e. it could be a rectangle or rhombus). From the question it just asks if it *could* form a square, which seems weird.